# Translation progress is lost after updating symfony translation

Tags: translation, symfony, weblate

I've setup Weblate to handle my symfony website translation and synchronize over GIT.

Weblate pick up correctly the translation file, proceed with translation and push properly the translation files.

However, once I want to update the new strings to translate, using:

```
php bin\console translation:update --force --output-format=xlf en
```

Then I push it on GIT and pull on Weblate, but Weblate loses all the translation progress and have to go back to square one.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : It seems like Weblate adds a field "approved=yes" which gets removed by symfony.

Answer (score 0):

As per XLIFF specification, only the strings with `aprroved="yes"` attribute are considered translated. Unfortunately Symfony doesn't follow the specification here.

Fortunately Weblate has workaround, see [documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#xliff).

Comment: Thanks Michal, I found this option, but because symfony put a string by default in the translated part, everything comes up as translated.